# pandas group bar chart

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot group bar chart

```
df1=sample_data.sort_values("Population")
df2=df1[(df1.Population < 500000)]

df3=df2[["city_id","CAC","Avg check"]]

df3.plot.bar(rot=0)
```

When the last command plots entire dataframe, I really wanted to use city_id as X label, and could not figure out how to make it done. Would anyone advise me on a right way?

Thanks,
Evgeny.

Comment: `df3.plot.bar(x='city_id')`?

Comment: Thanks, indeed, it works now.